# How can I maintain deferred execution with EF while projecting into another type?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm using EF 4 and I need to find a way to maintain deferred execution and project into another type.

This is my existing code:

```
AppointmentRepository appointmentRepository = new AppointmentRepository();
var appointmentGridItems = from a in appointmentRepository.ListAppointments()
                           select new AppointmentGridItemViewModel(a);
```

This code throws the following runtime exception:

"Only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in LINQ to Entities."

Is there any other way to shape the linq statement to accomplish what I am after?

Problem Context (if any cares or it has any baring): I need my appointment list serialized as JSON, however serializing the EF ObjectSet results in a circular reference error in the JSON. I the result from my repository has to be deferrable because the grid component I am using (from Telerik's ASP.NET MVC controls) requires it so that data paging can be managed in the DB instead of the View.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var appointmentGridItems = from a in appointmentRepository.ListAppointments().AsEnumerable()
                           select new AppointmentGridItemViewModel(a);
```

...will do it. Yes, this is still deferred. `ToArray` or `ToList` would not be deferred; `AsEnumerable` is.

If you can do something like:

```
var appointmentGridItems = from a in appointmentRepository.ListAppointments()
                           select new AppointmentGridItemViewModel
                           {
                               Appointment = a
                           };
```

Then you can do it completely within L2E. See [this post](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/12/31/38500/) for more examples. L2E supports POCO projections (even in EF 1); it just requires a parameterless constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and for correcting my knowledge on Enumerable.